# How to get values from database to set valies ina list view according to alpherbatical order

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

This is my code so far to retrive values from database to the listview. I need to make them appear according to alphabetical order. How should I change this code?  Please help!

```
  public List<Units> getAllUnit() {
          List<Units> unit = new ArrayList<Units>();

          SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UNITS,  null);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {
                unit.add(new Units(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)) , cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3)));
        }
             while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();
         return unit;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your query like this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT *
        FROM " +tableName +" ORDER BY " +yourcolumnName+ " DESC", null);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_UNITS ORDER BY YOUR_COLUMN_NAME;`

You can use `ASC` and `DESC` command after `ORDER BY` in order to get the data as per your requirement i.e. you want to show in alphabetical order or reverse alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this piece of code to order the list alphabeticly.
the `object2.yourparameter` is the parameter that you want to order on.

```
Collections.sort(unit, new Comparator<Units>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(final Units object1, final Units object2)
                {
                    return object1.name.compareTo(object2.yourparameter);
                }
            });
```

or you could change your query like said above